# Как получить ID последней записи SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

У меня есть ListView, по нажатию которой открываются детали.

```
int selectedId;

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), BookDetails.class));
            selectedId = bookingHistoryObjects.get(position).getId();
        }
    });
```

База:

```
public List<BookDetailsObjects> getAllBookingDetailsObjects(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    BookDetailsObjects bookDetailsObjects = new BookDetailsObjects();
    List<BookDetailsObjects> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    Cursor cursor = db.query(BOOKING.TABLE_BOOKING, new String[]{
                    BOOKING.KEY_ID, BOOKING.KEY_DETAILS}, BOOKING.KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(cursor.getString(1));

            bookDetailsObjects.setPNR(jsonObject.getString("PNR"));
            bookDetailsObjects.setDate(jsonObject.getString("DATE"));
            bookDetailsObjects.setDepartDate(jsonObject.getString("DEPART_DATE"));
            bookDetailsObjects.setFromTo(jsonObject.getString("FROM_TO_CODE"));
            bookDetailsObjects.setValidUntil(jsonObject.getString("VALID_UNTIL"));
            bookDetailsObjects.setTotalPrice(jsonObject.getString("TOTAL_PRICE"));
            bookDetailsObjects.setRoute(jsonObject.getString("ROUTE"));
            bookDetailsObjects.setFlightClass(jsonObject.getString("CLASS"));
            bookList.add(bookDetailsObjects);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return bookList;
}
```

Детали:

```
 DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(BookDetails.this);
 allBookItems = dbHelper.getAllBookingDetailsObjects(BookingHistoryFragment.selectedId);
```

Но мне еще нужно с другой страницы по нажатии кнопки переходить к деталям,  и присвоить к selectedId последний ID, которого у меня нет...

**Так вот, как мне получить последний ID?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил, наконец-то. Может кому поможет!

```
public long getLastInsertId() {
    long index = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase sdb = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sdb.query(
            "sqlite_sequence",
            new String[]{"seq"},
            "name = ?",
            new String[]{BOOKING.TABLE_BOOKING},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        index = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("seq"));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Что то не очень понятно, каким образом тут получается последний ID

Answer (score 0):

Если поле ID автоинкрементное тогда можно выполнить запрос вида: "SELECT last_insert_rowid()...."